# Why do I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_most_recent_post_of_user()?

Tags: functions

I am using WordPress 3.4.2. The codex doesn't say anything about this function being deprecated: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_most_recent_post_of_user

Comment: Are you using multisite?

Comment: No, I am not using multisite.

Comment: deprecated, rather than depreciated :)

Comment: I've just added to the Codex that it only works on Multisite :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get_most_recent_post_of_user() is for multisite installs to get the most recent post of the user from each blog.

Here is a comparable function you can use that will return the post object of the defined users most recent post.

```
function wpse_get_user_recent( $user ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $recent  = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID, post_date_gmt FROM {$prefix}posts WHERE post_author = %d AND post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 1", (int)$user ), ARRAY_A);

        if( ! isset( $recent['ID'] ) )
            return new WP_Error( 'No post found for selected user' );

    return get_post( $recent['ID'], 'ARRAY_A' );

}
```

Usage:

```
$post = wpse_get_user_recent( 36 );
setup_post_data( $post );

the_title();
the_content();
wp_reset_postdata();
```